# If statement fails with regex comparison

Tags: regex, if-statement, comments, rascal

```
public list[str] deleteBlockComments(list[str] fileLines)
{
    bool blockComment = false;
    list[str] sourceFile = [];
    for(fileLine <- fileLines)
    {
        fileLine = trim(fileLine);
        println(fileLine);
        if (/^[\t]*[\/*].*$/ := fileLine) 
        {
            blockComment = true;    
        }
        if (/^[\t]*[*\/].*$/ := fileLine) 
        {
            blockComment = false;
        }
        println(blockComment);
        if(!blockComment)
        {
            sourceFile = sourceFile + fileLine;
        }
    }
    return sourceFile;
}
```

For some reason, I am not able to detect `/*` at the beginning of a string. If I execute this on the command line, it seems to work fine.

Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong? In the picture below you can see the string to be compared above the comparison result (false).

[image: code execution snapshot]

Answer (score 1):

`[\/*]` is a character set that matches forward slash *or* star, not both one after the other. Simply remove the square brackets and your pattern should start behaving as you expect.

While we're at it, let's also get rid of the superfluous square brackets around `\t`

`^\t*\/*.*$`

Comment: I was able to fix it. Thanks!